# Equivalent of CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

What is the equivalent of [`CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in ASP.NET 5 (vNext)? When compiling against ASP.NET Core 5.0 and trying to call that method, I get the following error:

> ASP.NET Core 5.0 error CS0117: 'CultureInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetCultureInfo'

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2 and RTM use constructor parameter:

```
var ruCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
```